# flutter view not showing up

Tags: flutter, dart, email-verification

i was working on registration screen and after the registration i wanted to show a screen that says verify email with a link to send a verification but it's not working here is the code -

```
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:nxtreame/firebase_options.dart';
import 'package:nxtreame/views/login_view.dart';
import 'package:nxtreame/views/register_view.dart';
import 'package:nxtreame/views/verify_email_view.dart';


void main() {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  runApp(
    MaterialApp(
      title: 'Nxtream demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        
        colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSeed(seedColor: Colors.deepPurple),
        useMaterial3: true,
      ),
      home: const HomePage(),
      routes: {
        '/login':(context) => const LoginView(),
        '/register':(context) => const RegisterView()
      },
    ),
  );
}

class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  const HomePage({super.key});

  @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      return FutureBuilder(
          future: Firebase.initializeApp(
                      options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,
                    ),

          builder: (context, snapshot) { 
            switch (snapshot.connectionState){
              case ConnectionState.done:
                final user  = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
                if (user != null){
                  if(user.emailVerified){
                    print('Email is verified');
                  }else{
                    return const VerifyEmailView();
                  }
                } else {
                  return const LoginView();
                }
                return const Text('Done');
              default: 
                return const CircularProgressIndicator();
            }  
          },
        );
    }
}
```

as you can see in the code if the user.emailVerified is true it will print out email verified but if not it will return VeryifyEmailView but it's not

i tried everything i know

Answer (score 0):

The code you've written looks mostly correct, but it's possible that the problem might lie within the Firebase configurations or in the process of handling user authentication.

Let's ensure that the Firebase configuration and user authentication flow are working as expected

```
class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  const HomePage({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder(
      future: Firebase.initializeApp(options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
          final user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
          if (user != null) {
            if (user.emailVerified) {
              // Navigate to the main app screen as the email is verified
              // You can replace the commented line with your desired destination
              // For instance, Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, '/mainScreen');
              print('Email is verified');
              // Replace 'const Text' with the destination you want after email verification
              return const Text('Email Verified. Proceed to main screen.');
            } else {
              // The email is not verified. Navigate to the email verification screen
              return const VerifyEmailView();
            }
          } else {
            // User not logged in, navigate to the login screen
            return const LoginView();
          }
        } else {
          // Return a loading indicator while initializing Firebase
          return const CircularProgressIndicator();
        }
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Here are some correction i have made on your code to handle the registration & verification
If your Firebase configurations are correct, and the user authentication process is functioning well, the code above should properly handle the navigation to the VerifyEmailView or the main screen based on the user's verification status

Comment: it's still the same, one thing i notice is when i hot restart it the verification view will popup